# How does Assembler find variables in memory?

Tags: variables, assembly, x86-16, memory-address, memory-segmentation

I'm pretty new to Assembly but I know some of the basics.
So let's say we have a variable `var` (Byte) in a data segment `DataS`.
When the instruction `MOV AL, var` is executed, how does the assembler find `var`?

I mean how does it go from reading a set of characters (var) to finding it's address in memory, or rather, it's displacement relative to DS?
and what part does the directive `ASSUME DS:DataS` play in this process? Isn't having `DataS`'s adress in the register DS enough?

Comment: The assembler translates the human readable source code into binary machine code for the processor.  Everything in machine code language is encoded as a number for the processor, including the address of variables, branch target lables, etc..

Comment: The assembler doesn't "find" an address for `var`, it assigns an address to `var`, usually based on where `var` is defined in the source code, including which segment it is defined in.

Comment: The assembler will keep a symbol table to map from human-readable address labels to machine-readable memory addresses. It *must* have such a table, if only for cases where the label is only resolved by the linker (statically or dynamically at load- or runtime).

Comment: Yes, I am aware everything is in binary, the instruction above is 8A06XX where XX is the effective adress of {var} in hexadecimal over 16 bits. My question is how does the assembler find the pre given adress of this variable when it reaches this readable instruction?

Comment: @Tarmius It either knows the address or leaves a *relocation* telling the linker to fill in the address during linking.

Comment: The assembler assigns the addresses of labels based on what it sees preceding in the program.  When the address is known the instruction can be completed.  This may take 2 passes or fixups if the label is a forward reference.  But suffice it to say that it can figure that out sooner or later, certainly by the end reading the source code, and, that's its job.  The linker does similar, resolving external symbols between object modules by concatenating them together and identifying where symbols end up and what relocations (references to them) need fixing up.

Comment: *When the instruction `MOV AL, var` is executed, how does the assembler find var?* - terminology: the assembler only does anything when it's *assembled*, turning that source line into machine code.  For a flat binary, it may fill in an absolute address for `var`, otherwise leave it for the linker with relocation metadata.  When it *executes*, the CPU will read machine code containing an absolute address.  That absolute address could(?) even have been modified as the program loaded into RAM, if runtime fixups for the load address were necessary, instead of just via segment bases.